# Create a Filtered View to show rows with any values in an array of cells

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find a way to set a filter to show rows with any values in an array of cells?

ie I would like to create a filter to only show rows that have any values in the following columns
UPC-21
UPC-22
UPC-23
UPC-24
UPC-25

Data

[image: Full Data Set]

Desired result

[image: Filtered Data Set]

Have looked a lot online but have not seen any examples that match this scenario

Sample sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dAIPftLQ6N0UfrCHYF8brJAtyxmzcPTQw3NzGn4qEro/edit#gid=0

Comment: You will need to manually exclude viewing empty cells across all columns. Please include an *editable* sample sheet so others can show you the location of the toggles in answers and so we can have the question resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```cpp
=LET(f,FILTER(B3:G,LEFT(B3:G3,3)="UPC"),
     FILTER(f,BYROW(f,LAMBDA(r,COUNTA(r)<>0))))
```

We are essentially filtering out the columns whose header does not start with `UPC` then we are removing the empty rows.

Comment: OK great! Can you also help me to understand how this would differ if you were needing to Filter out for any header column that does not start with a set of 2 Values. ie if the last value was UNP-25, so I need to filter out any columns whose headers do not start with UPC or UNP? I also linked the work sheet in the Q as well now

Comment: your sheet is view-only. Please update the sharing settings to Anyone with the link -> Editor.

Comment: Sorry about that! Updated!